# How to get the count of all the web element in a web page that contains "ID" attribute?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to search in internet but unavailable to fetch any solution  for the above problem.
I  think we can get the value of id using the code below.
driver.getAttribute("id");

but how to capture all ids ??
**The Objective  of my test Script is to confirm no element in a web page has duplicate id .**
code is needed in Java.

Comment: let me rephrase it you want to count total number of tags with id as one of the attribute,now you want to find value of these id attribute, is it correct?

Comment: if yes then i don't think two different id will have same value but anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please try it like below

```
// opening Firefox Browser
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// for simplicity i have used below URl as solution
driver.get("http://docs.seleniumhq.org/");

// take each and every tag which have id attribute inside the list
List<WebElement> myTagsWithId = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id]"));
// if in case you want to work with xpath please use By.xpath("//*[@id]")

// Print the size of the tags
System.out.println("Total tags with id as one of the attribute is : " + myTagsWithId.size());

// now printing all id values one by one
for(int i =0;i<myTagsWithId.size();i++){
System.out.println("Id Value is : " + myTagsWithId.get(i).getAttribute("id"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the elements which has 'id', You can simply use contains in xpath and '*' to accept any element regardless of the type.

```
List<WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'') ]"));

//here '' is an empty char 

int size = lst.size();
```

I believe that you are trying to findout a solution for some issue and hope you are done with everything else except the id issue, if you could post the whole issue / challenge that you are facing..definitely you will get some clarity...

Answer (score 0):

Quick code

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("page_that_you_want_to_check");

    List<WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'') ]"));

    Map<String, Integer> checkList = new HashMap(); 

    for(WebElement ele : lst) {
        String currentId = ele.getAttribute("id");
        if(!currentId.equals(null) && !currentId.equals("")) {
            if(checkList.containsKey(currentId)) {
                checkList.put(currentId, checkList.get(currentId)+1);
            }
            else checkList.put(currentId, 1);
        }
    }

    for (String key : checkList.keySet()) {
        if(checkList.get(key) > 1) {
            System.out.println("There are: " + checkList.get(key) + " with ID " + key);
        }
    }
    driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code if you are using POM Framework;

```
//get total number of products available and print its name from a[anchor tag] in POM Framework
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='product_grid_display group']//div[@class='grid_product_info']//a")
private List<WebElement> AllProductName;
public void GetAllProductWithCount()
{
    // take each and every tag which have a [anchor] attribute inside the list
    List <WebElement> TotalProducCount = AllProductName;
    // Print the size of the tags
    int size =TotalProducCount.size();
    System.out.println("Total Products are : "+size );
    // now printing all anchor tag values one by one
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("TotalProducCount is "+TotalProducCount.get(i).getText());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Count and print the total number of hyperlinks present on google.com

```
package p1;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class CountUrl {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/mcastudent/Downloads/software/geckodriver" );
         WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.get("https://www.google.com");
         //List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
         List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
         System.out.println("No. of links: "+links.size());

}
}
```